# How to use retrofit partMap upload multiple Base64 encoded images？

Tags: java, android, base64, retrofit, retrofit2

```
for (String _selectedPhoto : pSelectedPhotos) {

        File _file = new File(_selectedPhoto);
        if (_file.exists()) {
            RequestBody _requestBody = RxPartMapUtils.toRequestBodyOfImage(_file);
            RequestBody _requestBody = RxPartMapUtils.toRequestBodyOfImage(Base64Utils.getStringFile(_file));
            map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + _file.getName() + "", _requestBody);

        }
    }
```

I tried to upload it in a file, but he didn't seem to work.